# Javascript/jQuery: How to identify the selected item based on tab press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

I am struggling to identify the element currently selected/focussed/highlighted by the tab key.

I am trying to fire a function on the enter keypress for the currently selected item. The code should be fairly self explanatory however my issue is that currently, I can tab to the selected `tr` (which contains the `data-href` attribute) press enter and then the logged `this` is the `body` element.

```
$(document.activeElement).keypress(function (event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    //console.log(this);
    onRowClick();
  }
});

function onRowClick() {
  var href = $(this).data('url');

  if (href != undefined) {
    window.location.href = href;
  }
}
```

I have tried replacing `$(document.activeElement)` with:

- `$('tr:focus')`
- `$('tr:active')`

Simplified Version: https://jsfiddle.net/stucare/59ghLmtv/

I hope this makes sense and is laid out appropriately.
Thanks in advance.

Table HTML (CSHTML)

```
<table id="ChainResultsTable" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Last Updated
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Last Updated
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Properties
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Properties
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Number of Properties
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Number of Properties
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Chain Status
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Chain Status
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            @if (Model.ShowChaseDetails)
            {
                <th>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            Activity
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            Activity
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </th>
            }
            <th class="scrollbarhead"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in Model.ChainSearchRowList.Data)
        {
            <tr data-chainid="@row.ChainId" data-url="/EstateAgents/ChainDetails/Index/@row.ChainId" tabindex="0">

                <td style="width: 150px">
                    @row.LastUpdated.TimeAgo()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Raw(row.Postcodes.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;").Replace(",", "&nbsp;&nbsp; "))
                </td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    @row.NodeCount
                </td>
                <td style="width: 120px">
                    @switch (row.ChainStatusId)
                    {
                        case ChainStatusValues.Active:
                            {
                                <span>@ChainStatusDescriptions.Active</span>
                            }
                            break;
                        case ChainStatusValues.Archived:
                            {
                                <span>@ChainStatusDescriptions.Archived</span>
                            }
                            break;
                        case ChainStatusValues.Complete:
                            {
                                <span>@ChainStatusDescriptions.Complete</span>
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                </td>
                @if (Model.ShowChaseDetails)
                {
                    <td>

                        @if (row.IsChasable)
                        {
                            switch (row.ChainChaseStatusId)
                            {
                                case ChainChaseStatusValues.ChaseInProgress:
                                    <span>Calling</span>
                                    break;
                                case ChainChaseStatusValues.ChaseWaiting:
                                <span>Waiting for Buyers</span>
                                    break;
                                case ChainChaseStatusValues.ChaseComplete:
                                <span>Complete</span>
                                    break;
                                case null:
                                <span></span>
                                    break;

                                default:
                                <span>Unknown</span>
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span></span>
                        }

                    </td>
                }

            </tr>
        }
        @if (!Model.ChainSearchRowList.Data.Any())
        {
            <tr class="no-results-no-hover">
                <td colspan="100%">
                    No Results
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can create a fiddle so we can help you

Comment: post your table html please

Comment: Added, I'm just creating a simplified fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/stucare/59ghLmtv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within JavaScript - referencing 'this' can have weird behaviour depending on usage and scope. There are many ways around it, such as binding elements to 'this' but in this case I think it would be best to pass the element that fired the event into the function that is going to handle the event much like so;

```
$(document.activeElement).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    onRowClick($(document.activeElement));
  }
});

function onRowClick(el) {
  var elhref = $(el).data('href');

  if (elhref != undefined) {
    window.location.href = elhref;
  }
}
```

In  the above, I am passing the element that is active at the time of the keypress into onRowClick, and then I can directly access that elements properties via 'el'.

Here is an updated JSFiddle showing the changes and the rows jumping to the anchor points.

[Updated JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/59ghLmtv/3/)

Comment: Be aware that if you want this to be accessible to screen reader users, there’s more work that will have to be done. There is nothing in the tr element that communicates the functionality. You’ll likely want to add an aria role of link and an aria-label that communicates the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To catch focus on a non-natively-focusable element assign tabindex=“-1” to that element.  Then the element will accept focus without being in tab order.  If you try to catch focus on a non-natively-focusable element without tabindex=“-1” focus will be assigned to the body tag.